# Can't get opacity to animate when using display: block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple tabs that I want to change out. I have the functionality working fine, however I cannot get the opacity to animate properly, the display seems to always override it and just display instantly. I've separated the opacity and display into separate classes which I add and also use a setTimeout to allow the opacity to fade out before the display fires

HTML:

```
<article id='about' class='content-hide'>
        <section>
            ABOUT - Lorem ipsum dolor
        </section>
    </article>

    <article id='projects' class='content-hide'>
        <section>
            PROJECTS - Lorem ipsum dolor
        </section>
    </article>

    <article id='contact' class='content-hide'>
        <section>
            CONTACT - Lorem ipsum dolor
        </section>
    </article>
```

JS:

```
var off = false;
function addAnimateListener() {
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('headerNav');
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {onclick(event.target);});
    }
}

function onclick(target) {
    document.querySelector('.header').classList.add('header-transition');
    var tabs = ['about', 'projects', 'contact'];
    for(var i in tabs) {
        document.getElementById(tabs[i]).classList.remove('content-show-op');
        document.getElementById(tabs[i]).classList.remove('content-show-dis');
    }
    var t = document.getElementById(target.innerHTML);
    if(off == false) {
        t.classList.add('content-show-dis');
        t.classList.add('content-show-op');
    } else {
        t.classList.toggle('content-show-op');
        setTimeout(function() {
            t.classList.toggle('content-show-dis');
        }, 1500);
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.content-hide {
    height: 20%;
    display: none;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 420px;
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}

.content-show-op {
    opacity: 1;
}

.content-show-dis {
    display: block;
}
```

NB: I don't want to use jQuery, just plain JS.

Comment: you dont need to select your tabs twice just use chaining document.getElementById(tabs[i]).classList.remove('content-show-op').remove('content-show-dis');

Comment: Why are you mixing css transitions and JavaScript? Its possible to do all the show and reveals using css and it is much quicker than JavaScript . The only draw back is css3 transitions are not supported by legacy browsers. Check www.caniuse.com for compatability.

Comment: [Uh, your code doesn't show anything for us to troubleshoot](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/Cr8FQ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your animation css into a separate class, then set the display block then add the animation class to the element

**CSS**

```
.content-hide {
    height: 20%;
    display:none;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 420px;
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    opacity:0;
}
.content-show {
    display:block;
}
.content-ani {
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s ease;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

**JS**

```
function show(id){
    var articles = document.querySelectorAll("article");
    for(var i=0; i<articles.length; i++){
        articles[i].classList.remove("content-ani");
        articles[i].classList.remove("content-show");
    }
    var ele = document.getElementById(id);
    ele.classList.add("content-show");

   //Needed to let the browser set the display before starting the animation
    setTimeout(function(){
        animate(id);
    },1);
    return false;
}

function animate(id){
  var ele = document.getElementById(id);
  ele.classList.add("content-ani");
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RBwRh/4/)